# Why does my app looks so big when viewing on a real device compared to on a simulator? react-native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing a react-native expo app where i'm using [native-base] as the design library.

When viewing my app on a iphone 13 pro max simulator it looks like this
[image]

this looks fine.

but when using a real device.
[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Everything is bigger. How can I fix this?

Thanks,
Arnav.

Comment: What kind of real device? Evidently not an iPhone 13 Pro Max

Comment: Hi @matt the real device is an iphone 8

Comment: So there you go. The interface is not bigger on the iPhone 8; the screen is smaller. Totally normal and correct. Don't worry be happy.